# Как получить список входящих на выбранный адрес транзакций в Web3.js?

Tags: blockchain, web3.js

Нужно получить все транзакции перевода токена на выбранный адрес. Иначе говоря все транзакции, где токен X отправлялся на выбранный адрес. Каким образом это можно сделать? В доках web3 не нашел подходящего метода. Вероятно, для этого нужно использовать какой-нибудь geth?
P.S. - В том числе нужны переводы на адрес от смарт-контрактов.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы хотите работать с токенами типа ERC20 - ловите событие Transfer. Для событий (Event) есть необходимые методы с настройкой фильтров. Транзакции Вы можете ловить только сканируя блоки. Транзакции от смарт-контрактов могут быть только внутренними - они не могут появится без порождающей транзакции, направленной на смарт-контракт.